# iOS Simulator 6.0 crashes with custom sort descriptor

Tags: core-data, ios6, nssortdescriptor

tAfter creating a Master-Detail Application project, I replaced the following line of code, in MasterViewController.m,

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
```

with

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
            initWithKey:@"timeStamp"
              ascending:YES
             comparator:^NSComparisonResult (id obj1, id obj2)
             {
                return NSOrderedSame;
             }];
```

This is the only change I've made to the Apple code template. When I run it on Simulator 6.0, the code crashes when fetching the data...

```
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
```

with objc_exception_throw. BTW, this code works on the Simulator 5.1. Any idea what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C based sort descriptors cannot be used with a fetch request.

From the "Core Data Programming Guide":

> ... To summarize, though, if you execute a fetch directly, you should
>   typically not add Objective-C-based predicates or sort descriptors to
>   the fetch request. Instead you should apply these to the results of
>   the fetch.

Btw, do you really want a sort descriptor that makes all objects equal?

Comment: @CodeMonkey: I cannot explain why it worked before and doesn't work anymore. I only know that the documentation states that you should not use Objective-C based sort descriptors for a fetch request. The reason is (I think) that the filtering and sorting is already done by the SQLite layer.